# Implicit route model binding parameter problems in middlewares

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a Course-Lesson-Question laravel App.

I have a simple Course class like this :

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'course_id';
}
```

And my routes are like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'Course'], function () {

            Route::group(['prefix' => '/{course}', 'middleware' => 'isThereCourse'], function () {

                Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'CourseController@course_details'])->where('course', '[0-9]+');

                Route::group(['prefix' => 'Lesson'], function () {
                    Route::group(['prefix' => '/{lesson}', 'middleware' => 'isThereLesson'], function () {
                        Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'LessonController@show_for_user']);
                });

           });
});
```

I want when user request a url like `/Course/5` show to him course details .for that I wrote `course_details` function  like this :

```
public function course_details (\App\Course $course)
        {
            $course_categories = $course->course_categories()->get(['name'])->lists('name');
            $org_levels        = $course->org_levels()->get(['name'])->lists('name');

            return view('main/pages/course/course-lessons', compact('course', 'course_categories', 'org_levels'));
        }
```

As you see in `course_details` and it's related route `Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'CourseController@course_details'])->where('course', '[0-9]+');` I used **implicit model binding** to access Course model that sent via url. in this case all things work fine.

Now user can go ahead,and may to show details of lesson of that course.for example user can request a url like this:

```
/Course/5/Lesson/1
```

For that I wrote another function named `show` like this :

```
public function show_for_user ($id, \App\Lesson $lesson)
{
$lesson = Lesson::with(['homeworks', 'files'])->find($lesson->lesson_id);
}
```

In this case `$id` parameter is id of the Course that current lesson is belongs to that and I want to be sure that course Id exists.

For that I wrote a middleware named `isThereCourse` with below content:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
      Course::findOrFail($request->course->course_id);
      return $next($request);
}
```

Problem is that in middleware, `$request->course` refers to different objects in different url.

When open `/Course/5` , `$request->course` refer to an Course model object but on opening `/Course/5/Lesson/8` , that only refer to ID of a Course model. Because of this ,on different url requests `isThereCourse` middleware return an error like this :

```
ErrorException in isThereCourse.php line 19:
Trying to get property of non-object
```

How can I mange parameter sent to middleware So that no error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my middleware like this:

```
public function handle ($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $course = $request->course;

            if (
                is_a($course, '\App\Course')
                or
                (is_numeric($course) and !is_null(Course::find($course)))
            ) {
                return $next($request);
            }

            return response()->view('errors/user/403', ['error_msg' => 'Course Not found']);
        }
```

First check `$course` parameter that is an Instance of `Course` Model otherwise if it is a number,find a `Course` Model with that id and if one of these condition was true I completed the request.

Answer (score 1):

check your middleware.

Basically, you need to debug in your middleware and $request class is an object itself. So you have to check by this:

```
dd($request->course->toArray());
```

If  `$request->course` is giving you an object of `Course` class, then you can get its output in array for easily understand the data.

I think this will help you for debugging.